# Button displayed on next screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I have a button on one fragment designed as follows :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tag="ActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
...

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateActivity"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/create"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

`OnClick` of this button, I am moving to another fragment :

```
btnCreateActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim, R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
                    WebFragment fragment = WebFragment.newInstance(Globals.TGURL_CREATE_ACTIVITY, "");
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_activity_layout, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

When the **WebFragment** (next screen) loads, **btnCreateActivity** is still there.

**fragment_web layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webFragment"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="truegroups.activities.WebFragment"
    android:background="#ffffff">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webFragment_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> This is specific only to few devices like Galaxy Note 3, Galaxy S3.

On rest of devices it works correctly and the button is not displayed on next screen.
Why so ?

Comment: what is the background of fragment_activity_layout, if no background then set a color.

Comment: @arun : fragment_activity_layout is the first screen. How shall setting the background of first screen fix this ?

Comment: which layout you are using for WebFragment

Comment: @user3676184 : Relative Layout

Comment: No. Are you using same layout for both fragment. Means R.id.fragment_activity_layout this layout

Comment: @user3676184 Separate layouts.

Comment: fragment_activity_layout add a child view as fragment. so it doesn't remove. you need a layout with no child.

Comment: that's why you passing the R.id.fragment_layout_activity

Comment: @arun : Didn't get your point "you need a layout with no child"

Comment: fragment_layout_activity use framelayout correct. Instead use linearlayout with vertical orientation now run application. You can get my point.

Answer (score 0):

The new fragment which you have called, comes on the top of the stack. Since it has transparent/null background, so the controls on the lower fragment remains visible.

Comment: Updated my question. I am already setting background of new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Put your button out side of framelayout